# Using Multiple SUMIFS in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

How would one go about changing this formula of sumifs into an VBA macro.

```
=SUMIFS('Staff Allocation'!N3:N6,'Staff Allocation'!B3:B6,Sheet2!A1,'Staff Allocation'!E3:E6,Sheet2!B1,'Staff Allocation'!F3:F6,Sheet2!C1)
 +SUMIFS(Modules!H2:H4,Modules!B2:B4,Sheet2!A1,Modules!G2:G4,Sheet2!B1,Modules!E2:E4,Sheet2!C1)
```

So it can be used in an if formula not =0 then do a specified action else move to the next process.

A1 is the first criteria value,
B1 is the second criteria value,
C1 is the third criteria value

Comment: Have you tried the macro recorder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use [Application.WorksheetFunction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff841212.aspx) to access worksheet functions. 
According to [the documentation for SumIfs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193011.aspx) you need to provide your arguments as `Range` objects.

So you need to take each range you want to evaluate and declare it as a range object.  In Excel, the [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) is a member of the [Worksheet object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff194464.aspx) so you need to specify which worksheet the range is on.   You can do this by specifying the name or index number from the [Sheets Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff193217.aspx). 
E.g. `Sheet2!A1` can be obtained using `SomeRange = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")`

Now, the Worksheet object is a member of the [Workbook Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff835568.aspx), so you can also specify what workbook you want - but if you read through the documentation links above, you'll see that the default for the Sheets collection is the ActiveWorkbook - so we'll rely on this to keep the example simple.

So to pass all your SumIfs arguments you could do something like below. 
Granted this might not be the most elegant solution, I think it should be easy enough to understand how it works.

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim Arg1 as Range
    Dim Arg2 as Range
    Dim Arg3 as Range
    Dim Arg4 as Range
    Dim Arg5 as Range
    Dim Arg6 as Range
    Dim Arg7 as Range
    Dim Arg8 as Range
    Dim Arg9 as Range
    Dim Arg10 as Range
    Dim Arg11 as Range
    Dim Arg12 as Range
    Dim Arg13 as Range
    Dim Arg14 as Range

    Set Arg1=Sheets("Staff Allocation").Range("N3:N6")
    Set Arg2=Sheets("Staff Allocation").Range("B3:B6")
    Set Arg3=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    Set Arg4=Sheets("Staff Allocation").Range("E3:E6")
    Set Arg5=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
    Set Arg6=Sheets("Staff Allocation").Range("F3:F6")
    Set Arg7=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1")
    Set Arg8=Sheets("Modules").Range("H2:H4")
    Set Arg9=Sheets("Modules").Range("B2:B4")
    Set Arg10=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
    Set Arg11=Sheets("Modules").Range("G2:G4")
    Set Arg12=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
    Set Arg13=Sheets("Modules").Range("E2:E4")
    Set Arg14=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C1")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Arg1,Arg2,Arg3,Arg5,Arg6,Arg6,Arg7)
     + Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Arg8,Arg9,Arg10,Arg11,Arg12,Arg13,Arg14) > 0 Then
        'Do Something
    Else
        'Do Something Else
    End IF
End Sub
```